# Typescript: How to type React abstract components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having an issue trying to type an abstract component in Typescript (coming from a lot of flow experience.) - The below examples are using Typescript 3.8.3

The code is:

```
const useSlot = (): [React.ReactNode, React.ComponentType] => {
    const slotRef = useRef();
    const Slot = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }): React.ReactNode =>
        slotRef.current ? createPortal(children, slotRef.current) : null;

    return [<div ref={slotRef} />, Slot];
};

export default useSlot;
```

And the usage is:

```
const [slotLocation, Slot] = useSlot();

return (
    <div>
        {slotLocation}
        <Slot>Some content</Slot>
    </div>
);
```

The problem I have is I cannot find any generic React component type searching online... In flow we would use a `React.AbstractComponent<Props>` type to cover any kind of react component. But I cannot find an alternative in Typescript, I've seen `React.Component`, `React.FC` and `React.ComponentType`; but none of them is working. Apparently it doesn't allow returning `ReactNode` (specifically the `string`) from those component types.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.

20         render(slotLocation)
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

error TS2322: Type '({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode; }) => React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
  Type '({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode; }) => React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.

12     return [<div ref={slotRef} />, Slot];
```

How can we type a generic component type that can return any kind of React node?

Comment: The most generic type is `JSX.Element`

Comment: @RobCo `JSX.Element` is the same as `ReactNode`; it's a rendered node. In this case I want to return a React Component that we need to call in order to render; e.g. `<Slot />` vs `<div>{slot}</div>`. Using `JSX.Element`, we get this error `JSX element type 'Slot' does not have any construct or call signatures.` (because it's not a callable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to type the `ref` to pass it to `createPortal`

Second the return type of `Slot` is `ReactPortal` and not `ComponentType`

You should also let TypeScript infer as much as it can, type only what TypeScript can't infer

I'm returning the array `as const` to type the position of the elements instead of explicitly typing the return type of `useSlot`

```
const useSlot = () => {
  const slotRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const Slot = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) =>
    slotRef.current ? createPortal(children, slotRef.current) : null

  return [<div ref={slotRef} />, Slot] as const
}
```